# Обособление уточнений - имён собственных

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

Растолкуйте, пожалуйста, обособление уточнений-дополнений, выраженных именами собственными (или наоборот – их уточняющих).

1. "В Сочи, на юге Краснодарского края, находится..." ("Уточнение" не сужает понятие. Юг большой. Точнее как раз название города. Но тогда оно перед уточняемым). Или аналогично: "Полковник Соколов, командир части, был..." (Разве имя не точнее, чем "командир", которых миллионы?)
2. "Российские спортсмены, Иванов и Сидоров, после душа направились..." (Явное уточнение: не все российские спортсмены, а только двое конкретных. Но и без запятых прекрасно...)

Или всё это на усмотрение автора?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Построение предложения должно выражать определенную **семантику,** при этом уточнение — это обычно сужение понятия.

**Примечание:** В очень редких случаях речь идет о расширении понятия, например: Он очнулся на кровати, в большой и светлой горнице.

**1) В Сочи, на юге Краснодарского края, находится...**

Предложение не совсем корректно, так никто не напишет. Все знают про город Сочи, даже те, кто не слышал о Краснодарском крае. Такая запись предполагает, что есть **несколько городов с таким названием**, и речь идет о том, что находится в Краснодарском крае.

**2) Полковник Соколов, командир части, был...**

Соколов — известная фамилия, не исключено, что там было **несколько Соколовых.** Но рассказ ведется о том Соколове, который является командиром части.

**3)Российские спортсмены Иванов и Сидоров после душа направились...**

**Уточнения нет.** Информация  относится к Иванову и Сидорову и одновременно указывается, что они являются российскими спортсменами.

4) **Российские спортсмены, Иванов и Сидоров, после душа направились...**

Речь, вероятно,  идет о группе **из разных стран,** кто куда направился, поэтому фамилии даются как уточнение.

Answer (score 0):

В случае с *Сочи* автор взялся уточнить малосведущим читателям, где именно находится Сочи (как следует из порядка слов). Формально это *сужает* для таких читателей область поиска в догадках "где же это?", что и определяет пунктуацию.

*Полковников Соколовых* тоже в стране может найтись много, и уточнение ориентирует условный "поиск" такого полковника на конкретную воинскую часть (этот Соколов не просто звание такое имеет, он - здешний командир). Отсюда и запятые при выбранном порядке слов.

Что касается *спортсменов*, то у автора есть выбор - в зависимости от того, что он пытается сказать. Если речь идёт о спортивной делегации, представленной на соревнованиях только этими двумя спортсменами ("а это Иванов и Сидоров"), то упоминание их имён с обособляющими запятыми уточнит такой факт; акцент останется на "российских спортсменах" (общий смысл сохранится и без имён). Без запятых остаётся неопределенность относительно того, были там другие российские спортсмены или нет. То есть, грамматически возможны оба варианта, но при различающихся смыслах.